MQTT with queues
I have an application sending MQTT messages, that cannot be changed.
There is a MQTT subscriber that is not always connected to the MQTT broker, so it could lose messages.
I need to enqueue messages on the broker, somehow, to decrease the possibility to lose them when the subscriber is not connected (retained message is not enough).
Is there a solution that allow to receive MQTT messages and put them inside queues, to consume via java clients?
I want to move from:
Publisher MQTT   --> MQTT Broker --> MQTT subscriber
to:
Publisher MQTT   --> MQTT Broker with queue --> Java consumer
I was thinking to RabbitMQ with MQTT plugin, but it seems that it allows only to receive on queues and publish in MQTT as per the following diagram:
Publisher on queue  --> RabbitMQ queue --> MQTT subscriber
Do you know if it's possible to design the desired pattern by configuring somehow RabbitMQ? Or are there other kind of platforms doing the desired scenario, with Java libraries?
Thanks in advance

Can you change the "MQTT Subscriber"? If so you should be able to achieve this without any additional components; the MQTT protocol offers delivery guarantees. If you connect with CleanSession=false, and subscribe with QOS>0, then the server will store messages for the subscriber whilst it's offline (see here and here for some info to get you started).
